# How could I make a program not show up in the processes tab?

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

Thanks for looking at my problem. I know my title makes it sound like I am trying to program a virus, hopefully you will believe me when I try to explain myself.

This semester I am doing an internship at a network security research group on campus. One of my first tasks was to create a program that can take a screenshot of each window when it became the *active window*. The idea is we are going to infect a computer with malware and my program will take a screenshot each time the malware does something. One small issue is that the malware will shut down all nonessential processes currently running. I need to hide my screenshot program in an essential process so it can continue to take screenshots even after the malware closes the nonessential processes.

My screenshot program is briefly described on this question I asked earlier this week:
[My code takes a screenshot of a program when it becomes the foreground window. Running into a small issue with the timing of the screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880473/my-code-takes-a-screenshot-of-a-program-when-it-becomes-the-foreground-window-r/18880763?noredirect=1#18880763)

The researchers are telling me that I will need to use hooks. I have tried to find some resources on this subject but there isn't a whole lot of documentation and if I ask on a different forum people just accuse me of making a virus. So here I am, thanks again for the help!

Comment: If your coworkers know the answer... why aren't they telling you?

Comment: Well, you essentially are making a virus :) But that isn't necessarily a bad thing. An understanding of how viruses work is required be able to fight against them.

Comment: They sound more his educators than his coworkers, @Nate.

Comment: @Nate He is away for the week so I am trying to get this done without the use of in-house help. Thanks again!

Comment: Try looking at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H). It might help you out

Comment: Go read `Professional Rootkits` by Ric Vieler, that will explain how to hide your process.

Comment: Working at a security research firm without knowing about windows hooks or code injection? Writing 'white hat' malware professionally in c#? Doesn't pass the sniff test IMO.  What you are asking for is not hard, but I'm really not comfortable helping people trying to break into malware/virus development.

Comment: @Yaur You may have missed it, but I said I am an intern. My university has a coop program and I ended up getting a job on campus at a network security research group. The program I am doing is meant to take screenshots of the malware so we can see what is going on. A lot of malware will shut down all nonessential processes so I am trying to hide it in order to not be shut down.